# Extracting a required string form a string stored in txt file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the below information in a txt file which is of 300lines

```
5.2.7.1  timer value  ($D125)
5.2.7.2  Power back information  ($05B2)
5.2.7.3  Time Since power off  ($05B4)
5.2.7.4  highspeed mode State  ($0730)
```

I want the below information to be read and stored two different strings

For Example

```
str1 = timer value
str2 = D125
```

Need a PYTHON Script , compatible with PYTHON 2.7.5.

Comment: and what have you tried?? We can't just make it for you; you need to show some effort. You can always post a job at upwork if you need someone to write the whole code for you

Comment: I created and updated the text file with above information in PYTHON , but after that i am stuck . I am a beginner in PYTHON thats the issue

Comment: This looks more of a requirement than a question!

Comment: Still just a hint, use RegEx, make your pattern and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to python and have no experience, but I managed to develop the code below which is not the best code possible, but I guess the output is exactly what you want:

```
import re

f = open('a.txt').readlines()
str1 = []
str2 = []
for i in f:
    res = re.sub("\n", '', i)
    res = re.sub("\d.\d.\d.\d  ", "", res)
    str = re.split("\(\$", res)
    str[1] = re.sub("\)", '', str[1])
    str1.append(str[0])
    str2.append(str[1])
print(str1)
print(str2)
```

As @Milind mentioned, RegEx could help you find patterns. 
I assumed that txt file's name as `a.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_1= str[str.find(start_str)+len(start_str):str.rfind(end_str)]
```

All you have to do is initialise `start_str = "XXXXXXX"` and `end_str = "YYYYY"`.